# AWS ElasticCache - Cross Site - Disaster Recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, memcached, disaster-recovery, amazon-elasticache

I'm using AWS ElasticCache (MemCached) and can see how instances can be created at different data centers/sites. (eg: singapore A or B)

There is no AWS Automatic Replication of ElasticCache from DataCenter to DataCenter...

Therefore is there a way to replicate cache from one site/dc to another? Thus allowing a successful Fail over of Cache...

Comment: [You don't want this.](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringClient#Failure,_or_Failover)

Comment: I want to know how to do this... is it possible to replicate cache like this? ... just learning... (how to cross site replicate cache?)

Comment: Anyone... is this possible???

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to automatically do this.

You could write a simple script in your language of choice to manually replicate keys to a different region.  I'm not really sure why you'd want to do this though?  The network latency introduced from traveling half-way around the world would negate any benefits of memcache.  You're better off replicating your persistent datastore and then having a separate memcache cluster in from of that data in each region.